Unit test fails for deep_update method with sets and tuples - unexpected behavior
I'm having an issue with a deep_update method that's supposed to recursively update a dictionary, including merging sets when encountered. However, my unit test is failing specifically for the case involving sets. This is the function
@staticmethod
    def deep_update(main_dict: Dict, update_dict: Dict) -> None:
        """
        深度更新字典
        :param main_dict: 原始字典
        :param update_dict: 新字典
        :return: 更新后的字典
        >>> dict1 = {'a': {'b': 1}}
        >>> UseDict.deep_update(dict1, {'a': {'c': 2}})
        >>> assert dict1 == {'a': {'b': 1, 'c': 2}}
        """
        for key, value in update_dict.items():
            if key in main_dict:
                main_value = main_dict[key]

                # Deep update for nested dictionaries
                if isinstance(main_value, dict) and isinstance(value, dict):
                    UseDict.deep_update(main_value, value)

                # Concatenate lists
                elif isinstance(main_value, list) and isinstance(value, list):
                    main_dict[key] = main_value + value

                # Union sets
                elif isinstance(main_value, set) and isinstance(value, set):
                    main_dict[key] = main_value | value

                # Concatenate tuples
                elif isinstance(main_value, tuple) and isinstance(value, tuple):
                    main_dict[key] = main_value + value

                else:
                    # Update primitive types or handle other types directly
                    main_dict[key] = value
            else:
                # If key doesn't exist in main_dict, add it
                main_dict[key] = value

        return main_dict


These examples work alright. But the unit test for the set and tuples doesn't:
Examples:
# Example 1: Deep update with nested dictionaries
main_dict = {'a': {'b': 1}}
update_dict = {'a': {'c': 2}}
print("Input (Nested Dicts):")
print("Main Dictionary:", main_dict)
print("Update Dictionary:", update_dict)
UseDict.deep_update(main_dict, update_dict)
print("Updated Dictionary (Nested Dicts):", main_dict)
# Expected Output: {'a': {'b': 1, 'c': 2}}

# Example 2: Deep update with lists
main_dict = {'a': [1, 2]}
update_dict = {'a': [3, 4]}
print("\nInput (Lists):")
print("Main Dictionary:", main_dict)
print("Update Dictionary:", update_dict)
UseDict.deep_update(main_dict, update_dict)
print("Updated Dictionary (Lists):", main_dict)
# Expected Output: {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]}

# Example 3: Deep update with sets
main_dict = {'a': {1, 2}}
update_dict = {'a': {3, 4}}
print("\nInput (Sets):")
print("Main Dictionary:", main_dict)
print("Update Dictionary:", update_dict)
answer = UseDict.deep_update(main_dict, update_dict)
print(answer)
# print("Updated Dictionary (Sets):", main_dict)
# Expected Output: {'a': {1, 2, 3, 4}}

# Example 4: Deep update with tuples
main_dict = {'a': (1, 2)}
update_dict = {'a': (3, 4)}
print("\nInput (Tuples):")
print("Main Dictionary:", main_dict)
print("Update Dictionary:", update_dict)
UseDict.deep_update(main_dict, update_dict)
print("Updated Dictionary (Tuples):", main_dict)
# Expected Output: {'a': (1, 2, 3, 4)}


Tests:
def test_deep_update():
    # Test with nested dictionaries
    main_dict = {'a': {'b': 1}}
    update_dict = {'a': {'c': 2}}
    useDict.deep_update(main_dict, update_dict)
    assert main_dict == {'a': {'b': 1, 'c': 2}}

    # Test with lists
    main_dict = {'a': [1, 2]}
    update_dict = {'a': [3, 4]}
    useDict.deep_update(main_dict, update_dict)
    assert main_dict == {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]}

    # Test with sets
    main_dict = {'a': {1, 2}}
    update_dict = {'a': {3, 4}}
    UseDict.deep_update(main_dict, update_dict)
    assert main_dict == {'a': {1, 2, 3, 4}}

    # Test with tuples
    main_dict = {'a': (1, 2)}
    update_dict = {'a': (3, 4)}
    useDict.deep_update(main_dict, update_dict)
    assert main_dict == {'a': (1, 2, 3, 4)}

    # Test with conflicting types (dict vs list)
    main_dict = {'a': {'b': 1}}
    update_dict = {'a': [2, 3]}
    useDict.deep_update(main_dict, update_dict)
    assert main_dict == {'a': [2, 3]}  # List should replace the dict

Expected for sets:
assert main_dict == {'a': {1, 2, 3, 4}}

Expected for tuples:
assert main_dict == {'a': (1, 2, 3, 4)}


In your test code there is only the problem that in some tests you use the instruction useDict.deep_update(...) instead UseDict.deep_update(...). Are you sure that if you execute the test you have some problems?

This passed all tests when I copied your code.

your method randomly references UseDict explicitly. That does not seem correct to me.

Thanks all, for the replies. As @kenny-ostrom said. The code was working. All I had to do was pip install . again after I wrote the code because I was referencing some new modules or libraries in the test

The answer was to do a pip install . again after writing the tests. And the code worked
